# Could this be a tooth or a fossil, looks like a molar

Tags: oceanography, fossils

Found at shore off Genoa, Italy.  My kids really think it’s a molar of some kind.. [image]

Comment: we need at minimum a measure of size like a photo with scale and pics from different angles. It may be a tooth but from just this photo it is impossible ot tell.

Comment: it looks like granite with quartz on top,something for scale had been helpful.